# were completed/being completed

Tags: word-usage

1) The revenue and profit of the property development segment dropped 13.8% and 5.5% respectively due to lower sales and declining contributions as a result of more projects **were completed** in first half of 2014.

2)The revenue and profit of the property development segment dropped 13.8% and 5.5% respectively due to lower sales and declining contributions as a result of more projects **being completed** in first half of 2014.

Which of the above sentence is grammatical ? Should I use a passive voice "were completed" or a passive gerund "being completed" ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not identify any particular issues or concerns regarding the text. Please, edit your question and describe your concerns.

Comment: The way I see it, the question is about whether "as a result of" is followed by a noun phrase or a clause.

Comment: Yes,this is what I am trying to ask . Tq

Answer (score 1):

Being completed is correct. If you want to use **were completed** you could say

> The revenue and profit of the property development segment dropped 13.8% and 5.5% respectively due to lower sales and declining contributions **since** more projects were completed in first half of 2014.

Comment: Wouldn't you use because instead of since?

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> 1) as a result more projects were completed (remove "of")

or

> 2) as a result of more projects being completed

Comment: I understand that "as a result" is a CONJUNCTIVE ADVERB, does it mean that "as a result of" is a preposition ?

Comment: As I read it, in 2) "of more projects" is a prepositional phrase.